# Commas with subordinating conjunctions

Tags: word-order, clauses, commas

I have read in grammar books that  a comma is usually used when making a complex sentence. For instance:

> 1. If you keep talking to your mother like that, I will have to teach you manners.
> 2. Although she is smart, I won't give her the job.

On the other hand, I have also read that a comma is not needed when the independent clause comes first except when the dependent clause is a "non-defining clause". So,

> 3. She likes soap operas, which I find boring.
> 4. They finished the job on time, which they rarely do.
> 5. That house,which is for sale, belongs to a German family.
> 6. I won't let you go to any parties anymore  if you keep telling me lies.
> 7. She is really shy whereas her sister is really talkative.

I made up the above sentences, so they may sound not really natural or even wrong in terms of meaning, but the grammar aspect is my goal here.

Last but not least, I wrote the following sentence:

> 8. I'm willing to help her although she has always been very rude to me.

But somebody corrected it like this:

> 9. I'm willing to help her, although she has always been very rude to me.

I thought that a comma was not needed when the independent clause appears first. (Except the non-defining clause case)

Answer (score -1):

Well according to my knowledge

we can use commas to join two sentences, which can be related to each other or talking about only thing.
or if second sentence giving more information about first one. 
like

> I like oranges, if they are fresh.
>   I love to go with you, but have some work to finish

check below rules for commas:

1. Use a comma before any coordinating conjunction (and, but, for, or, nor, so, yet) that links two independent clauses.
   Example: "I went running, and I saw a duck."
2. Use a comma after a dependent clause that starts a sentence.
   Example: "When I went running, I saw a duck."
3. Use commas to offset appositives from the rest of the sentence.
   For example, "While running, I saw a mallard, a kind of duck." "A kind of duck" is the appositive, which gives more information about "a mallard."
4. Use a comma after introductory adverbs.
   "Finally, I went running."

http://www.businessinsider.in/THE-COMMA-SUTRA-13-Rules-For-Using-Commas-Without-Looking-Like-An-Idiot/articleshow/22667230.cms

follow this , Added example according to your question

Comment: Yep, your second example " I (d)love to go with you,but I have some work to do" as a compound sentence is ok to me,but I'm still in doubt about first one "I like oranges,if they are fresh". I'm not saying it's incorrect;I just think there might be a grammatical explanation for it .In fact,that explanation is what I'm looking for.

Comment: please check, I have updated the answer and added link to follow for further digging.

Comment: The link you gave was really useful,and it's actually raising a lot of questions about punctuation rules I didn't know.

Comment: Sorry,I was halfway through typing when I submmited the comment by mistake.

Comment: Sorry ,but again ,something is wrong with my phone..my question is- In the complex sentence " I'll help her, although she has always been very rude to me", can  the dependent clause after the comma be "considered as"an appositive,or is it indeed an appositive?I mean,apart from a dependent clause, is appositive the technical name given to that clause?

Comment: The example you have given is supplementary to the first statement. Yeah there also you can use `, comma`

Comment: Commas are intended to make text more readable and understandable.  I'm not sure where this usage of coordinating comma before *and/but* started but I cannot see any reason for it.  *I went running and I saw a duck.*  Why the comma?  I don't see an independent clause.  If you didn't see the duck while you were running, a comma won't help relay that information.  *I went running yesterday, and Skylab fell from space in the Seventies.*  There is how you use that comma on an independent clause but I would never link independent clauses with an *and* and a comma.  It's terrible.

Comment: *I [would] love to go with you, but have some work to finish.*  The second part of your sentence is not independent of the first.  It is very dependent on the first part of your sentence.  No comma - just use the conjunction on its own.